# Getting object from fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, getter

My fragment2 class has an array of students, I want to get the array from my activity class.

My activity class extends AppCompatActivity implements Communicator. I need it to extend AppcompatActivity because Im using a toolbar.

Activity class handles the communication between Fragment 1 and 2. Anyone has any solution on how to do this?

Comment: So from the fragment you want to access the array that's in the Activity? or you want to access the array in the activity from the fragment?

Comment: No I have an array in the fragment2, I want to access it from the activity

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface in your Fragment that is implemented by your Activity.

More info [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to reuse the `Fragment` UI components, you should build each as a completely self-contained, modular component that defines its own layout and behavior.

An `Activity` can act as a container of the `Fragment`s. So, if one `Fragment` needs to pass something to another `Fragment`, it can pass it to the `Activity`, which in turn can pass it to the other `Fragment`.

The ideal way of doing it is to have a Callback interface defined in your `Fragment` and have the `Activity` implement it. In your `Fragment` you call one of the Callback methods passing it the array or the item. In the implementation of the method, in the `Activity`, it can consume it / pass it to other `Fragment`.

More information on `Fragment` - `Activity` communication is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to access objects inside a fragment from the hosting activity, you would typically hold a reference to the fragment inside the Activity and call a 'get' method directly on the fragment.

If it is the reverse (Fragment > Activity) you would have the Activity implement some sort of interface, and inside the `onAttach()` method of the fragment you would cast the Activity (or Context) to the Interface.

Comment: Fragment1 adds names from edittext > Activity passes name to F2 > fragment2 adds names to array and displays the names in a listview. I want to get the array from Fragment 2, so the best solution would be to create a instance of fragment2 in my activity class and get the array? would that get the array?

Comment: I believe you should use the interface. That way when the array is ready you can simply pass it to the Activity and the Activity can handle it from there.